# How do I represent an IP address in an XML Schema Definition?

Tags: xml, xsd, ip-address

I would like to define a type in my XML Schema Definition (XSD) that represents an [IPv4 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Addressing) in [dot-decimal notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-decimal_notation), so that in my XML:

```
<Example>
    <Address>192.168.0.1</Address>
</Example>
```

will be validated as correct and incorrect values such as:

```
<Example>
    <Address>192.268.0.1</Address>
</Example>
```

are rejected as invalid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solution

Use the following type definition in your XSD file:

```
<xs:simpleType name="IPv4Address">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>IPv4 address in dot-decimal notation. Equivalent to [0-255].[0-255].[0-255].[0-255]</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This will only accept values 0 to 255 in each of the four dot-separated fields.

### Explanation of the Pattern

The pattern is:

```
((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])
```

which is just this group clause:

```
(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])
```

repeated `{3}` three times with a `\.` dot after it and then one more time without the dot.

The `|` bars break that group clause into three alternative matches:

`1?[0-9]?[0-9]` matches all numbers from 0 to 199.
 `2[0-4][0-9]` matches three digit numbers starting with a 2, from 200 to 249.
 `25[0-5]` matches 250 to 255

### Example Use in Schema

Once defined the type can be used in the schema like this:

```
<xs:element name="Example">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Address" maxOccurs="1" type="IPv4Address" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but doesn't account for a couple of edge cases likely to arise in real-world use cases. In many cases, the first and fourth bytes should not be `0`, so it may be desirable to use a pattern like `1[0-9]?[0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]` for one or both of them.

Comment: In case there are others reading this useful post wondering specifically about schema specification of UDP Multicast address... ((22[4-9]|23[0-9])\.)((1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){2}(1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])

Answer (score -1):

Edge cases can be handled via a light update of the original regexp:

```
([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}
```

Numbers from 1 to 99 will be explicitly validated based on the 2 first parts of this regexp:

```
1 digit:  [1-9]
2 digits: [1-9][0-9]
```

Comment: This will not even match 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @svenhuebner: thanks for having spot this basic case.
I changed the regex accordingly so that it should catch-up all allowed values.